# Multiple lines ButtonGroup in react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-bootstrap

I'm new to react, but I have a good experience with bootstrap, and using bootstrap before I have, multiple times, did a ButtonGroup where the buttons go into multiple line. 
Right now I am working with react, and trying to do the same thing using react-bootstrap, but it doesn't seem to be possible. This is a what I'm doing so far:

```
<ToggleButtonGroup vertical type="radio" name ="options">
  <ButtonGroup justified> 
   <ToggleButton>1</ToggleButton>
   <ToggleButton>2</ToggleButton>
  </ButtonGroup>
  <ButtonGroup justified>
   <ToggleButton>3</ToggleButton>
   <ToggleButton>4</ToggleButton>
  </ButtonGroup>
</ToggleButtonGroup>
```

This, to my understanding, corresponds to the way of doing it with bootstrap and html, but it's still showing all buttons in vertical and not in two rows as intended

**EDIT:**

Here's an example of what I'm looking for: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4WAc.png)

To clarify more, the two lines belong to the same group, so only one option from the two lines can be chosen at once.

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of what you have and what you expect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using vertical in your ToggleButtonGroup component, remove that and
instead of using ButtonGroup you should be using ToggleButtonGroup and to render both groups on separate rows you should wrap them in toolbar like

```
  <ButtonToolbar>
    <ToggleButtonGroup type="radio" name="options" defaultValue={1}>
      <ToggleButton value={1}>Radio 1</ToggleButton>
      <ToggleButton value={2}>Radio 2</ToggleButton>
      <ToggleButton value={3}>Radio 3</ToggleButton>
      <br/>
      <ToggleButton value={4}>Radio 4</ToggleButton>     
      <ToggleButton value={5}>Radio 5</ToggleButton>
      <ToggleButton value={6}>Radio 6</ToggleButton>
    </ToggleButtonGroup>
  </ButtonToolbar>
```

Comment: This isn't really what I'm looking for, I want the same button group to be divided into two lines instead of being displayed in a single line, and both need to be in the same group so toggling works over all of them.